# Cannot POST /ha use more then one FORM

Tags: html, node.js, express

I was trying to send more then one `FORM`, but I get an error.

The first `FORM` works the second one doesn't. It's the same form.

The second one gives me an error `Cannot POST /ha`

```
<body>
  <form action="/ha" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="submit" value="Senden">
  </form>
  <form action="/Gehalt" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="submit" value="Senden">
 </form>
</body>
```

this is my test.js

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();

let Gehalt
let r

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));


let db = new sqlite3.Database('memory.sqlight3', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log('Connected to the chinook database.');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/test.html');
});

app.post('/ha', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Yout got it");
  r = req.body.user;
  var stmt = db.prepare('INSERT INTO lorem (Salary) VALUES(?);');
  stmt.run(r);
  stmt.finalize();
  db.close();
});


app.post('/Gehalt', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Yout got it");
  r = req.body.user;
  var stmt = db.prepare('INSERT INTO lorem (Outgoings) VALUES(?);');
  stmt.run(r);
  stmt.finalize();
  db.close();
});

app.listen(3100, function() {
  console.log('GO to Port 3100');
});
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the specific error you're getting. See [MCVE] for more info.

Comment: I don’t get any error message, only message i get is that “cannot post/ha” << this is my err.messge